# Poll and get MQTT messages from AJAX in browser

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mqtt

Beginner here.

Ok, I'm trying to accomplish a simple data flow:

MQTT-Data-source ---> MQTT Broker ---> NodeJS-MQTT-Client ---> AJAX-on-web-browser (polling-every-3-seconds)

- I want to be able to get the MQTT message and show it in the AJAX component in browser side.
- Secondly, on `console.log(mqttMessage);`, how do i clear previous messages? Because on console I can see all previous data as well as the new data adding up.

I'm using mqtt.js for my nodejs mqtt support on Express.

```
//Server.js
var mqtt            = require('mqtt');
...
...

var getData = function() {
    mqttClient.subscribe(mqttTopic);

    mqttClient.on('message', function(topic, message) {
        mqttMessage = message.toString();
        console.log(mqttMessage);
    })

    return mqttMessage;
}

app.get('/pollData', function(req, res) {
    res.send(getData());
});
```

And on a simple html page, I've got:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function() {
            setInterval(function() {
                    $.get('/pollData', function(res) {
                        $('#data').text(res);
                });
            }, 3000);
        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Any reason to use AJAX polling rather than just use MQTT over Websockets to deliver the MQTT messages directly to the page?

Comment: @hardillb I thought it might be flexible to have the server handling all MQTT messages first and spewing out the data in whatever format... as an AJAX return, or database query, or JSON response...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. There is no benefit if at all if your just passing the message on and this adds way more load to the server.

Comment: @hardillb Thank you. I suppose you're right. Thank you for your answer, but I think I'll take up your suggestion and move on to Paho MQTT JS client.

Comment: IMHO there's nothing wrong with using the intended "pattern". To prepare the data on the back-end/server side hides complexity from the web client, it is more secure (i.e. no direct MQTT client access), easier to manage/pre-process the data and doesn't rely on WebSockets, which are still not as widely supported as AJAX. - As always, it depends on the use case...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a REALLY bad pattern, you should just use the Paho MQTT Javascript client and subscribe to the topic directly from the web page.

But if you really want to do it this way then the following is the right way to do it.

```
//Server.js
var mqtt            = require('mqtt');
...
...

var mqttMessage;

mqttClient.subscribe(mqttTopic);

mqttClient.on('message', function(topic, message) {
    mqttMessage = message.toString();
    console.log(mqttMessage);
})


app.get('/pollData', function(req, res) {
    if (mqttMessage) {
        res.send(mqttMessage);
    } else {
        res.status(404).send();
    }
});
```

This is because you don't read a value from a MQTT topic, you have to wait until somethings is published on that topic, then the broker will forward it to all subscribers. So in the code above you set up the connection, subscribe, then when a message is published it is stored in the `mqttMessage` variable, then if it's not undefined it can be returned by the REST end point.