# Showing MQTT response on a node server API

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mqtt

I'm trying to output the response I receive from MQTT to a node serve setup using express.

There will be a json string message received from the mqtt service at every second.
The response would be output on `/main` API, which I would call from a Ionic 4 mobile app I'm working on.

However, now I can't display the data on the server itself just to check, I haven't thought of how I would constantly update the data as well on the server. The page doesn't refresh it just keeps loading.

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const express = require('express')

const PORT = 8000
const app = express()

var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://bac.com")

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("Connected")
    client.subscribe('/test')
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("ROOT");
});

app.get("/main", (req, res) => {
    client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
        res.send(message)
    })
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: server side events or web sockets - the former is probably the "lighter" and easier to implement option since the data will be a one way deal from server to client

Comment: Why subscribe server side when you can subscribe in the HTML page is self with MQTT over Websockets

Comment: @hardillb I'm trying to create an API that constantly sends a response (json). It's possible by displaying in a html page but I do not want to do that.

Comment: HTTP REST interfaces cannot keep sending results, if you want a constant stream of results use MQTT at the end consumer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46341080/poll-and-get-mqtt-messages-from-ajax-in-browser). On the server side it will send data on message received. On the client side, it is an ajax call for every second to retrieve the data on the server side.

As described in the link, it really is a bad pattern. However, this would be suitable for those who have constraints to making changes to the MQTT service.

```
// Server.js
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const express = require('express')

const PORT = 8000
const app = express()

var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://bac.com")
var mqttMessage

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("Connected")
    client.subscribe('/test')
})

client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    console.log('Topic: ' + topic + '\nMessage: ' + message)
    mqttMessage = message
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.get("/main", (req, res) => {
    if(mqttMessage)
        res.send(mqttMessage);
    else
        res.status(404).send();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

and on the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(
            function () {
                setInterval(function () {
                    $.get('/main', function (res) {
                        $('#data').text(res);
                    });
                }, 1000);
            }
        );
    </script>
    <p id="data"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store your data somehow on the server side for your approach to work.

Implement some kind of storage service that stores the messages. Your client will need to respond to the queue messages and push these to storage, your api action will retrieve them from the storage, not from the queue.

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 8000;
const app = express();
const storageService = require("SOME KIND OF STORAGE SERVICE");

var client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://bac.com");

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("Connected")
    client.subscribe('/test')
});
client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
    storageService.save(topic, message); //or this has to provide storage and enterpretation of the data comming in
});
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.send("ROOT");
});

app.get("/main", (req, res) => {
    res.send(storageService.getAll());
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

You could also revisit the entire implementation, and push messages to the frontend via a socket or some other kind of persistant connection.